# Custom headers higher than standard?

Tags: c++, header

Is it reasonable to put custom headers higher in `include` section than standard headers?
For example include section in `someclass.hpp`:

```
#include "someclass.h"
#include "global.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

Is it best practice? What is the profit if it is?

Comment: Why do you ask? Why do you think this might be better? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think that it does not actually solve any problem. I saw this as recommendation, but I cannot get the reason. I hope someone can make it more clear for me

Comment: The order of header files does not really matter. It only matters if one header file depend on another.

Comment: The reasons are only cosmetic. Assuming the header files are independent, any order will produce a valid program. Besides, I've never seen anyone say "oh look, these `#include`s are in the wrong order".

Comment: @user1035174: "I saw this as recommendation" From where?

Comment: @NicolBolas: To be accurate, it was not strict recommendation. It was declared that _some_ developers prefer to process in this way. From book about c++. I cannot find actual place where I saw it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that if you forget to include a dependent header in `someclass.h`, then whatever implementation file includes it as the first header, will get a warning/error of undefined or undeclared type, and whatnot. If you include other headers first, then you could be masking that fact - supposing the included headers define the required types, functions, etc. Example:

my_type.h:

```
// Supressed include guards, etc
typedef float my_type;
```

someclass.h:

```
// Supressed include guards, etc
class SomeClass {
public:
    my_type value;
};
```

someclass.cpp:

```
#include "my_type.h" // Contains definition for my_type.
#include "someclass.h" // Will compile because my_type is defined.
...
```

This will compile fine. But imagine you want to use use `SomeClass` in your program. If you don't include `my_type.h` before including `someclass.h`, you'll get a compiler error saying `my_type` is undefined. Example:

```
#include "someclass.h"
int main() {
    SomeClass obj;
    obj.value = 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It is fairly common practice to `#include "widget.h"` *as the first thing* in `widget.cpp`. What this does is ensure that `widget.h` is self-contained, i.e. does not inadvertently depend on other header files.

Beyond that, I think it's essentially a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

There are two important observations to be made before delving in the specifics:

1. When you develop a new header/source pair, it is important to check that the header is self-contained. To do so, the easiest way is to include first in a file.
2. It is best not to include extraneous things before including a header you do not own, as this could create strange issues in case of conflict of macros or overload of functions.

Therefore, the answer depend if you have unit test or not.

A general rule of thumb is to include headers starting with the Standard Library, then 3rd party headers (including Open Source projects), then your own middleware, utilities, etc... and finally the headers local to this library. It more or less follows the order of dependencies to comply with *observation 2*.

The only exception I have seen was the *one* header corresponding to the current source file, which would be included first to make sure it is self-contained (*observation 1*)... but this only holds if you don't have unit tests, for if you do then the unit test source file is a very good place to check this.

Comment: "It more or less follows the order of dependencies" - IMO that's the problem. If "my own middleware" uses but forgets to include a "3rd party header", I don't want that mistake hidden because all my .cpp files "helpfully" decided to include things in order of dependency. All else being equal it's good to write your code in a way that shows up errors elsewhere. But your point about tests is spot-on: you can write as many tests as you like that include header files singly or in multiple different orders, rather than relying on a limited number of .cpp files to do ad hoc tests.

Comment: Oh, and the same goes for "strange conflicts". I don't want to write a header file that accidentally relies on `<iostream>` not being included after it, and inventing a style rule that `<iostream>` must never be included after my header gives me more opportunity to do so.

Comment: @SteveJessop: if your own middleware is developped following *observation 1* (ie, self-containment test), then there is no issue :)

Comment: assuming my own middleware isn't a header-only library. Or if it is, then assuming that its own tests do as you suggest. I think I'm basically just saying that if I don't make a rule for include order, then I get more variety of use-patterns among internal clients of my code, and hence more opportunities to catch issues. It would be nice if my unit tests proved that my code is perfect in every respect, but in practice it turns out there are sometimes bugs anyway.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I understand what you mean, however I still prefer have a rule order (I usually separate the groups by space and order them alphabetically) because it makes checking the includes (at a glance) easier.

Comment: Yes, I see that benefit. And I also tend to use alphabetical order within the groups once the list gets too long to take in at a glance. But in the terms of the original question, I certainly wouldn't go so far as to say it's *not* reasonable to do otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the system headers.

If there are no dependencies between the headers both ways work, but since programming is essentially communication, not with the computer but with other humans, it is important to make it logical and easy to understand. And my opinion is that it is better to start with the system headers.

I base this one of my very first programming courses (in 1984, I think), where we programmed in Lisp and were taught to think like this: you start with the normal Lisp language, and then you create a new language that is more useful for your application by adding some functions and data types. If you for example add dates and the ability to manipulate dates, this new language could be called Lisp-with-dates. Then you could use Lisp-with-dates to create a new language with calendar functionality, which could be called Lisp-with-calendars. Like layers in an onion.

Similarly, you can view C as having a "core" language, without any headers, and then you can for example expand this language into a new, bigger language with I/O functionality by #including stdio.h. You add more and more stuff to the core language by #including more headers. (I am aware that the term "C language" in other contexts refers to the entire standard, with all the standard headers, but bear with me here.) Each new #included header creates a new, bigger language, and an additional layer of the onion.

Now, to me it seems that the standard headers obviously should be the inner part of this onion, and therefore before the custom headers. You can create the language C-with-monsters by adding stuff to C-with-I/O, but the people who created C-with-I/O did not start with C-with-monsters.

Answer (score 1):

While it is just personal choice, I would prefer to include standard headers first. Few reasons:

- Any set of `#ifdef..#define` would be correctly mapped, rather than standard headers misinterpreting them. This goes for conditional compilation as well as values of some macros, while standard headers are being compiled.
- Any change/new function in standard header may conflict with your function, and compiler would emit error in header file, which would be be complicated to solve.
- All required standard headers should be placed in one header (preferbly some pre-compiled-header), include that header, and then include your custom header. This would reduce compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

any place you include c++ compiler treats it as the same

Comment: Not necessarily. The preprocessor treats it the same, just a textual copy, but the overall effect would be very different if you #included inside a namespace for instance. This is a bad idea, and generally why all the includes are at the top - keeps them separate from anything else.

Comment: inside namespace is a different case. other than scope issues there is no performance gain with include at top or last or middle

Comment: @CodingMastero: Normally no performance gain, but there can be widely different behavior depending on the macros and functions in scope when including a given header...